# Receiving Build error after trying to build android project in VS 22

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

i am trying to build a Xamrin.Android project using Visual Studio 22, which was originally built using Visual Studio 2017.
I get the following error message and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required Android.Runtime.JNIEnvInit 
    method tokens at 
    Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.GetRequiredTokens(String 
        assemblyFilePath, Int32& android_runtime_jnienv_class_token, Int32& 
        jnienv_initialize_method_token, Int32& jnienv_registerjninatives_method_token)
        at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.AddEnvironment()
        at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.RunTask()
        at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in             
        /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android- 
            tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
```

UPDATE:
To reproduce the error:
I copied the project to another folder then opened it with VS 22.
Clean Solution , REbuild Solution, restart the IDE.
Error is still the same

I have absolutely no idea how to fix it

Comment: Have you tried to clean up the solution for your Xamarin project on VS 2022? Please refer to [To build, rebuild, or clean an entire solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#to-build-rebuild-or-clean-an-entire-solution), and restart the Visual Studio to build it again. If this solution doesn't resolve your issue, could you please update the detailed steps to reproduce the issue to the issue?

Comment: If using NuGet packages, ensure that you've chosen the same NuGet package manager settings. Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => Package Management

Comment: Looking at the source code for Xamarin, it looks like you're missing the Android SDK for Visual Studio 2022. You haven't really provided us with much to go on, so I'm just guessing at this point. If you've never built an Android app with VS 2022, you may be missing the necessary components. You can double check by opening the Installer and searching for "Android" components. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/ea8442b8c43c1b5983008163dc1fa17b2c8c695e/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Tasks/GeneratePackageManagerJava.cs#L465).

Comment: But if the Android SDK were missing wouldn't every newly created app in VS 22 produce errors?

Comment: @DaveR you never mentioned that you have been able to build newly created Android apps. Additionally, maybe the failing project is using an older version so newly created Xamarin Android apps work as expected. Unfortunately, without reproducible steps, it's really hard to offer better assistance. It may be worth looking through the Nuget packages, if there are any, and updating them if possible. Also, attempt to strip the project down to the bare minimum. If you can build new Xamarin projects, but not this one, there is something in your project causing the issue and this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to AndroidX.

> "AndroidX replaces the Android Support Library. This article explains
> why AndroidX exists, how it impacts Xamarin.Forms, and how to migrate
> your application to use the AndroidX libraries."

Here is a link to the migration instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. For a migration to AndroidX I need Xamarin.Forms. Besides, that's not what the error message refers to. Or do I see this wrong

Comment: I migrated to my Xamarin to .net and AndroidX, I could not find the root cause of the issue.